# MATLAB: 2D DATA TO 3D ! How to?

Tags: matlab

I have a `34200 x 4` table. This table shows the 30 years monthly amount of pr (precipitation) in some latitudes and longitudes. So the columns are `lat`, `lon`, `date`, and `pr`. I want to convert it to a 3D matrix that `longitude x latitude x month`. 
I attach my table. 
Please tell me how to do it I'm a beginner. If I don't want to convert it based on the month I could but this issue is so complicated for me.
[Please look at my table it's only 235 KB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3fgrrkc45iifgi/table.mat?dl=0) I upload it to my DropBox so please click on Open in the top right side and click download.

[Here is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCNAf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting your data, your latitude and logitude values actually represent 95 unique locations which are scattered seemingly randomly. You can see that in the figure below.

```matlab
length(unique(C.lat)) % 95
length(unique(C.lon)) % 95
scatter(C.lat, C.lon)
```

[image]

If the locations were spaced in a grid, it would make sense to use `lat` and `lon` as the axes of a data matrix. But instead, it is better to use only one axis representing the unique locations. This then leaves you with a second axis representing the date.

```matlab
length(unique(C.date)) % 360
360 * 95 % 34200 - the number of values we have
```

### Reformatting the data

Therefore, I would store the data in a 2D matrix as follows.

```matlab
locations_lat = unique(C.lat, 'stable');
locations_lon = unique(C.lon, 'stable');
dates = unique(C.date, 'stable');
data = reshape(C.pr, length(dates), length(locations_lat)); % size 360 x 95
```

Then, to check that this has worked, choose a random example.

```matlab
location_num = 27;
date_num = 242;
lat = locations_lat(location_num) % 14.68055556
lon = locations_lon(location_num) % 65.23111111
date = dates(date_num) % 2/1/2009
precipitation = data(date_num, location_num) % 16.7179
```

Searching for that position and date in the original tale, we have:

```
9602|   14.6805555600000    65.2311111100000    '2/1/2009'  16.7179000000000
```

Comment: Dear @Dominic D. Thank you so much. You right but if it is possible I wanter a 3D matrix. longitude x latitude x time. In fact, in the outputs, I don't want anything except pr data. Just like when we open a NetCDF data. Please look at the picture that I provide to my question.Thanks

Comment: @Aviva do you want interpolation/extrapolation then? To be able to create a 3D matrix you need values on all points on a regular grid.

Comment: Yeah, you can't have longitude x latitude as two axes because you don't have values for all those longitudes and latitudes. Like we say - this would mean having a grid of locations.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Yes, I want to have a 3 matrix to start interpolation my data using the griddata function in Matlab.
I want to perform my interpolation from longitude 62:0.5:80 and latitude: 7:0.5:22.

Comment: So what is the problem with that @AvivaAbelson ? You already know which function you need!

Comment: @AnderBiguri, The problem is griddata should perform for every month and every location. That's the reason that I want to have a 3D matrix with lon x lat x month. Do you say that I should first interpolation then generate a 3D matrix?

Comment: @AvivaAbelson you are looking for `meshgrid`

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is your data with the 4 columns `[34200x4]` then you can create a 3-dimensional matrix like this:

```
B = zeros(len(A),3)
B(:, 1) = A(:, 1)
B(:, 2) = A(:, 2)
B(:, 3) = A(:, 3)
```

Possibly even:

```
B(:,1:3) = A(:, 1:3)
```

Depending how your data is set, you may need to transpose which is:

```
B = 'B
```

You can map data over as long as the dimensions match.

You can implement a for loop if you have even more columns or for dynamic data entries.

Comment: While technically this solves the question asked, the truth is more complex. PP wants a 3D version of his data, which this code will create, but shuffled completely randomly. The dimensions won't have much meaning.

Comment: Thanks Ander, I see with the other reply the true requirement. Interesting case!